# Do I need clean Vdd when measuring resistance using ADC with Vref tied to Vdd?

Tags: adc, resistance, thermistor

I want to measure the resistance of the thermistor with the MCP3021 ADC using the voltage divider method. Since this ADC has Vref connected to Vdd and Vdd is powered from a DC/DC converter, I was thinking about adding LDO to make sure Vdd is clean, but I’m not sure if I really need one. My reasoning is that when the input of the ADC is connected to the ground, it will give minimal value, no matter what the Vdd is. When the input of the ADC is connected to Vdd, it will give the maximum value, no matter what Vdd is. When the input of the ADC is connected halfway between Vdd and ground, it will give a value of halfway, no matter what Vdd is. Since I don't need to get voltage but proportion between the values of two resistances, which doesn't depend on Vdd, I feel like I don’t really need clean and stable Vdd. Am I right?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuaj6b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the internal diagram from the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20001805C.pdf):
[image]

The input is sampled at one time, and Vdd is used as the reference at a somewhat later time.

If the wires to the thermistor are long, you'll probably find you need or want a capacitor across the thermistor, which will again cause some difference in the effective reference and the reading.

The stability over a relatively long period of time (say more than five of the longest time constant in the circuit) - which generally includes thermal effects- is much less important compared to the noise on Vdd, which can cause noise in the reading. If the noise on the Vdd is synchronized with the readings (likely due to something the MCU is doing) you can get systemic errors rather than just noise.

Comment: So, measurement is indeed independent of Vdd voltage but not independent of noise in it. I could add a resistor on Vdd to filter it out. Assuming I want to drop 0.5V with a maximum conversion current of 250 µA, that gives 2 kΩ; let's round it to 2.2 kΩ. This 2.2 kΩ, with the recommended 10 µF, gives a time constant of 22 ms. This 22 ms is nearly 2500 times longer than ~9µs of conversion time, which should be sufficient.

Comment: Sounds way more than necessary. Maybe 100 ohms and 10uF is more than adequate for the S&H part of the puzzle.